Maven Repository 404
почистил кэш в студии и перестал собираться проект.
пишет "не вижу модулей зависимостей" для Коина и еще одной библиотеки.
но я их вижу в репозитории мавена.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.koin/koin-androidx-viewmodel/2.0.1
а вот ни pom-файлы, на aar - не доступны
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/koin/koin-androidx-viewmodel/2.0.1/koin-androidx-viewmodel-2.0.1.pom
что делать?

Стоит обратить внимание на строку Repositories JCenter, почитать https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/ и поискать эти файлы на зеркалах.

А там написано что Relocated и версия уже 4.0.0

@Style-7 ну коин, это как пример. у меня есть библиотека, которая явно не такого уровня, не обновлялась уже давно и находится только на JCenter (в других репах ее нет). + в разных проектах (в которых я уже не учавствую) тоже есть такие небольшие либы.

@Wlad аналогичная ситуация, единомоментно(пару недель назад) получил 404-ую ошибку по трем "не особо популярным" библиотекам из JCenter, одну получилось найти в другом репозитории, для второй получилось скачать *.aar, ну а третью пришлось затащить в виде исходников с github.

@ermak0ff а на другом репозитории, это на каком? я в инете находил только гугловский и мавен, но там моих либ нету.

@Wlad SciJava Public Repository, вбивал либу(в данном случае это была com.github.aakira:expandable-layout) сюда - https://mvnrepository.com/, и искал по вкладкам нужную версию - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.aakira/expandable-layout?repo=scijava-public
